# Flask Jinja Macro: How can I have dynamic parameter name in URL_FOR?

Tags: flask, jinja2

```
{% macro dynamic(dynamic_param_name) %}
  ...
  <form action="{{ url_for('main.index', dynamic_param_name=1) }}" method="post">
  ...
{% endmacro dynamic %}
```

like: {{ dynamic_param_name }}=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url_for` accepts kwargs after first argument.

```
{% macro dynamic(**kwargs) %}
  ...
  <form action="{{ url_for('main.index', **kwargs) }}" method="post">
  ...
{% endmacro dynamic %}
```

When you need it, you can call it like this `dynamic(dynamic_first=1, dynamic_second=2)`.

edit:

If what you need is only to change the argument name dynamically, I think you could do it like this:

```
{% macro dynamic(param_name) %}
{% set keyname={param_name:1} %}
  <form action="{{ url_for('main.index', **keyname) }}" method="post">
{% endmacro dynamic %}
```

Comment: Thanks! 

But I wanted to change the KEY name dynamically (namefield), not to retrieve its value (1).


The left key part of this expression 
namefield=1

Comment: Genius! Thank you Agung! :)